# Which $n$-gons, inscribed in a circle, have the largest area?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Let $n$ be an integer, $n≥3$, and $H$ be a circle. Which (convex) $n$-gons, inscribed in $H$, have the largest area?

How can I use Lagrange multipliers to solve this?

Comment: I think if one focuses on three consecutive vertices, moving the middle one gives largest area when it lies at the bisector of the arc formed by the outer two. An argument like this would show that all the spacings are equal in a largest area $n$ gon.

Comment: The "moving" argument shows that if a maximum *exists*, then the maximum is indeed for the regular $n$-gon. Existence takes some work.

Comment: The areas of such $n$ gons are bounded above by that of the circle. However I see your point, e.g. the numbers in $(0,1)$ are bounded above by $2$ and yet have no maximum. If one could show the values taken on by the areas form a compact set, it would be done, however compactness might be more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are forced to use Lagrange multipliers to solve this, you may do like this:

Let assume that $H$ has radius 1. Also, let $O$ be the center of $H$ and let $\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_n$ be central angles formed by two consecutive vertices of the $n$-gon and $O$.

Simple geometric argument shows that if this $n$-gon achieves its maximal area, then we must have $0 < \theta_i < \pi$. Thus we may assume this condition without loss of generality.

Now, the area $S(\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_n)$ of the $n$-gon is

$$ S(\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_n) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin \theta_i, $$

where $(\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_n)$ varies in the set

$$ D = \{ (\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_n) \in \Bbb{R}^n : \theta_i \in (0, \pi) \text{ and } \theta_1 + \cdots + \theta_n = 2\pi \}.$$

Applying Lagrange multiplier to $S$, there exists $\lambda$ such that

$$ \nabla S = \lambda \nabla (\theta_1 + \cdots + \theta_n) = (\lambda, \cdots, \lambda). $$

That is,

$$ \cos \theta_i = 2\lambda \quad \forall i. $$

But since $\theta_i \in (0, \pi)$, there is a unique $\theta_i$, say $\theta_i = \arccos(2\lambda)$, that satisfies this equation, and this shows that $\theta_1 = \cdots = \theta_n$. This proves that the $n$-gon with the maximal area must reduce to a regular $n$-gon.